# How do I send notifications to a specific device using fcm-node package for firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notifications to a specific device using fcm-node package but I don't know how as it's not clear in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node)

this is my code:

```
let firbaseNotification = {
                notification: {
                    title: content.title,
                    body: content.message,
                    // content_available: true,
                    priority: 'high',
                    click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                    requestTime,
                    sound: 'default'
                },
                data: {
                    content,
                    action_loc_key: null,
                    content_available: true,
                    priority: 'high'
                }
            };

            var message = {
                notification: firbaseNotification.notification,
                data: firbaseNotification.data
            };

            firbaseNotification['registration_ids'] = deviceIds; // Device IDS

            fcm.send(firbaseNotification, function (err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    status = 400;
                    console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
                }

                res.send({ status, errorMessge: err });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error)
            res.send({ status: 400, errorMessge: error });
        }
    });
};
```

deviceIds is supposed to be the id of target devices in my db, how do I send to a specific user?

Comment: You have to record which devices are being used by which user.  FCM does not do that for you. It knows nothing about users, just devices.